# Eclipse error popup: "Certificate Problem"

Tags: eclipse, svn, certificate, sourceforge

For the past few weeks I keep getting the following error whenever I use the SVN plugin on Eclipse:

```
Certificate Problem
There is a problem with the site's security certificate
Error validating server certificate for: https://x10.svn.sourceforge.net:443
- Unknow certificate issuer
Fingerprint: .....
Distinguished name: GeoTrust,Inc., US
```

Selecting Trust Always doesn't do anything, just keps poping back up.  Tried reinstalling subeclipse and nothing.  Any thoughts on how to fix this?  Or at least how to turn off these damn certificate problem notifications?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the GoeTrust root certificate in your trusted root store?

Start > Run > mmc > File > Add remove snap in > Add... > Certificates > Current User > Done.

Under *Trusted Root Store* look for the GeoTrust certificate that matches the issuer on the certificate giving you the error. If it is not there you will have to manually install it.

Their root certs can be found here: http://www.geotrust.com/resources/root-certificates/

Comment: Hmm... ok and now to figure out how to do that for Mac :)
 Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, not sure how the certificate storage works for Mac. Download a certificate from that link and see if it prompts you to install it when you double click it, just a guess though.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using the Subversive plugin for Eclipse, and slikSVN as my repository.  I noticed the same issue with the popup constantly appearing even after clicking "Trust Always".

I found an alternative solution that can be done through Eclipse:

Go to **Window** -> **Preferences** -> Expand **Remote Systems** -> **Passwords** -> Click **Add** (for *Host Name*, add the URL that requires the security check on the popup, e.g. https://svn2.sliksvn.com:443, or in your case: https://x10.svn.sourceforge.net:443).  Choose the appropriate System Type (I used 'Default'), then fill in your SVN *User ID*, *Password*, and *Verify Password*.  Click OK, and that should work as well.